# LGPL Machine Learning with Random Forest - C++

Tags: c++, machine-learning, lgpl

I am looking for a library with following features:

1. Minimalistics with Random Forest
   learning and classification
2. LGPL licenced
3. In C++
4. CMake build system - not compulsory

So far [Waffles](http://waffles.sourceforge.net/) looks good, any other contenders ?

Comment: Looks like lack of karma points is discouraging people from answering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about [TMVA](http://tmva.sourceforge.net/) or [alglib](http://www.alglib.net/dataanalysis/decisionforest.php)?  I haven't used them personally, but the license terms look to be favorable for your uses, and both are C++.  Not sure if they have the specifics you're looking for, though.

Comment: Alglib looks quite nice and minimalisitic though the licence is GPL. Thanks for the links.

Answer (score 4):

Just for the record.

OpenCV has an implementation of several different machine learning algorithms (including multi-class probabilistic random forests).

See http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/random_trees.html

Comment: I have actually started using the OpenCV RF implementation as part of Remote Sensing classifiers in Orfeo.